# Nuxt: Generate does not create html for every route in static target

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I wish to generate html files for static deployment.

The package.json dependencies are as follows

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.15.1",
    "@nuxtjs/markdownit": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
```

The content directory is:

```
content
  blogs
     blog1
        cover.png  // image used as cover
        content.md // content of blog
     blog2
        cover.png
        content.md
     ...
```

The pages directory is:

```
pages
   blogs
     _slug.vue
   index.vue
```

The nuxt.config.js is:

```
export default {
  target: 'static',
  generate: {
    fallback: '404.html',    
  },
```

When I run `npm run generate`, this only creates a `index.html` in the `dist` directory. I would like a dist directory structure like:

```
dist
  _nuxt (dir)
  blogs
    blog1.html
  index.html
  ...
```

The following have been my observations:

1. If I add `ssr:true` or `ssr:false` in **nuxt.config.js** it seems to make no difference to the dist directory output.
2. If I add routes to the generate settings, it generates the output as desired

```
  generate: {
    ...
    routes: ['blogs/blog1']
  }
```

From the documentation I thought that nuxt automatically crawled for all routes and generated them.

Is there a way to get what I desire? Can I generate the routes by some looping logic? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### If you need to generate all pages

you must say which routes Nuxt should generate. There's no way it could know every dynamic route to be generated. Its crawler doesn't have your backend/api data so you must give it manually like you did, or by writing some looping logic that queries it.

Nuxt docs give some examples on how to achieve this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  generate: {
    routes() {
      return axios.get('https://my-api/blogs').then(res => {
        return res.data.map(blog => {
          return '/blogs/' + blog.id
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#function-which-returns-a-promise

### If you don't need to generate all pages

You can simply use Nuxt's fallback page for when a route (like `blogs/blog32`) doesn't exist. This way it tries to build the page via frontend routing, using your `_slug.vue` component.

To achieve this behavior, add a `fallback: true` to your generate settings

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    fallback: '404.html' //or true
  }
}
```

After that you should make sure that the webserver that the project is deployed on redirects to your 404.html. Some servers do this automatically, but others don't.

In my case (apache) I had to add to my `dist/.htaccess` file the following line for the redirect to happen

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#fallback

Comment: Thanks @Jose. In my use-case, since all the blogs are part of the content folder, I would have thought that there can be a way to specify the list of routes just like I am retrieving them in the Home Page of my site ... using the `await $content("blogs", ...)` in the asyncData of my index.vue

Answer (score 1):

It now seems to work. The following seems to work:

1. Added `ssr:true` in nuxt.config.js

```js
//nuxt.config.js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  
  ssr: true,

  generate: {
    fallback: '404.html',    
  },
  ...
```

Then,

2. Then, `npm run build`
3. Followed by, `npm run generate`

Now I notice that all the blog pages are getting generated in the `dist` directory

4. To confirm run, `npm run start`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (https://content.nuxtjs.org/v1/getting-started/advanced/#static-site-generation):

> Since Nuxt 2.14+, nuxt generate has a crawler feature integrated which will crawl all your links and generate your routes based on those links.

So Nuxt will generate pages that has a link within your site.

If you want to create a page for all your markdown files you can use this in your configuration:

```
generate: {
  async routes () {
    const { $content } = require('@nuxt/content')
    const files = await $content({ deep: true })
      .where({ extension: { $eq: '.md' } })
      .only(['path']).fetch()

    return files.map(file => file.path === '/index' ? '/' : file.path)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nuxt 3 SSR crawler needs to find the routes like a person would via surfing from page to page. Therefore, manually create a `/sitemap` (or whatever name) that loops through all of your routes and link to it in your footer or wherever. For example:

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, key) in posts">
      <NuxtLink :to="post.the_url">
        <span v-html="post.post_title"></span>
      </NuxtLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

BUT! Make sure that `post.the_url` is a *relative URL*, NOT an absolute URL. The crawler doesn't seem to crawl absolute URLs. To reiterate, make sure the outputted HTML of the sitemap is like:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/my-first-post-yay">
        <span>My First Posts Yay!</span>
      </a>
    </li>
...
  </ul>
```